# Record stereo from digital line in

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to get stereo samples from the digital line in on the iPhone/iPad. 
To get a stereo line-in, I use the Mickey Blue microphone "Addon" for iOS.

See [This](http://bluemic.com/mikey_digital/).

I use the Aruts iOS `CoreAudio` example from [Here](https://code.google.com/p/ios-coreaudio-example/).

This works perfect to get samples in mono from the line in, but I can't figure out the correct setup for stereo.

If there's anyone who can point me in the right direction that would be really helpful.
I need the samples directly to process them first, so writing to a file first is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

The `AudioStreamBasicDescription` will only accept 32bit per channel in stereo mode somehow. Using the code below enables getting the samples in stereo (currently only using additional hardware)

Here is the audio format I used to get it to work:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription stereoStreamFormat;
stereoStreamFormat.mSampleRate          = 44100.00;
stereoStreamFormat.mFormatID            = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
stereoStreamFormat.mFormatFlags         = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical;
stereoStreamFormat.mBytesPerPacket      = 4;
stereoStreamFormat.mBytesPerFrame       = 4;
stereoStreamFormat.mFramesPerPacket     = 1;
stereoStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame    = 2;
stereoStreamFormat.mBitsPerChannel      = 32;
```

Furthermore I use a separate buffer for each channel and a modified `AudioBufferList` struct :

```
struct AudioBufferListStereo
{
    UInt32      mNumberBuffers;
    AudioBuffer mBuffers[2]; //<-- this array has been set hardcoded to 2 channels because the standard iOS version did not work as expected.
#if defined(__cplusplus) && CA_STRICT
public:
    AudioBufferListStereo() {}
private:
    //  Copying and assigning a variable length struct is problematic so turn their use into a
    //  compile time error for eacy spotting.
    AudioBufferListStereo(const AudioBufferListStereo&);
    AudioBufferListStereo&    operator=(const AudioBufferListStereo&);
#endif

};
typedef struct AudioBufferListStereo  AudioBufferListStereo;
```

The complete source is quite long, so I'll post it on GitHub if anyone requires it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the `AVAudioRecorder` like this:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];

NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
//this should enable stereo
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

AVAudioRecorder *recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
recorder.delegate = self;
[recorder prepareToRecord];
[recorder record];
```

Comment: oh - since iOS7 you can set the preferredInputNumberOfChannels on the AVAudioSession. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but to my understanding AVAudioRecorder can only record to a file like in your example. I require the samples directly and raw to process them first.